# Apex callout exception when making hitting an external Service

Tags: apex, exception, wsdl, wsdl2apex, callout

I am looking at a strange exception when I make an apex callout to a external system. I am forming a very simple apex code to hit the endpoint using wsdl2Apex class. I get the below excception:

Exception:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: [ISS.0088.9164] Access to WSDescriptor wsdl2apexClassName.webservices:wsdlName denied. faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=http://..endpoint

Apex Callout Code:

```
    wsdl2apexclassName sample = new wsdl2apexclassName();
wsdl2apexclassName.input req = new wsdl2apexclassName.input();
sample.endpoint_x = 'the end point goes here';

sample.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Username','username');
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Password','pass');
wsdl2apexclassName.response res = sample.functionwhichhasInvokeMethod(req);
system.debug('******' + res);
```

WSDL has these information in the beginning:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions
> xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="wsdlName"
> targetNamespace="http://URL"
> xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
> xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
> xmlns:soapjms="http://www.w3.org/2010/soapjms/"
> xmlns:tns="http://URL****"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
> xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">   
<wsdl:types>
......
```

DEbug log:  CALLOUT_REQUEST

```
invokeMethod:[apex_schema_type_info=(http://endpoint, false, false), field_order_type_info=

(Input), Input=Input:[apex_schema_type_info=(http://targetURL, false, false), 

field_order_type_info=(listOfPfOrderOutboundIo), listOfPfOrderOutboundIo=null, 

listOfPfOrderOutboundIo_type_info=(listOfPfOrderOutboundIo, 

http://targetURL, null, 1, 1, 

false)], orderInput_type_info=(Input, 

http://targetURL, null, 1, 1, 

true)]::SOAPAction="SOAPAction" 

Accept=text/xml Username=usernamee**** User-Agent=SFDC-Callout/38.0 SFDC_STACK_DEPTH=1 

Password=**** Content-Type=text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you check the end point is accessible from browser?

Comment: @Ashwani Yes it is. In additional I am able to hit the endpoint using SOAP UI and get a successful response.

Comment: Looks like WSDL has access modifier issues. Can you check you have public attrib for `wsdlName`

Comment: @Ashwani I do not see any public there. Added the first couple of line from the WSDL in my question. Can you pls take a look

Comment: Can you capture the SOAP request SF is sending from your debug log? I imagine your request is improperly formed if you can hit it from a soap ui. There should be a line in your debug named `CALLOUT_REQUEST` that will show you the envelope being sent.

Comment: @JesseMilburn Please see my edit. I am not sure why the exception says denied. Why do you think request is not formed correctly?

Comment: @SfdcBat Because I was going through this yesterday with a Fedex tracking wsdl with a slightly different error. Anywho, that isn't the request I was after, wish I could put images here. There should be one right above that that has the actual SOAP envelope. Should just be an xml string.

Comment: @JesseMilburn Are you saying I am missing a SOAP envelop in my apex callout code? Can can find this xml string?'xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" '

Comment: Lets continue [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50921/soap-wsdl-chat)

Comment: @SfdcBat Are you certain the credentials should be in the HTTP headers? Maybe the need to be in the SOAP headers. If you can share the WSDL (without the endpoint if required) and the working SOAP UI request it would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yes I have included the credential in http header with SOAP UI. Earlier I had to do it using SOAP header but now the service provider asked me to send the credential only in http header itself. I specify the credential in SOAP UI properties section

Comment: @SfdcBat The sample code to call the web service from Apex looks a bit odd. Is `sample` actually a proxy class like `wsdl2apexClassName.webservices`. I say odd because it is usually an inner class that contains the web method proxies.

Comment: I had to shorten the names because of confidentiality but you are right it is a inner class which has a method to invoke webservice. wsdl2apexClassName is the wsdl2apex class name and webservices is a inner class, functionwhichhasInvokeMethod method has the  WebServiceCallout.invoke() method in it. Hope it is clear

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51146/discussion-on-question-by-sfdcbat-apex-callout-exception-when-making-hitting-an).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this erro was , I was passing the username and password in the wrong way in Http header like below:

```
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Username','username');
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Password','pass');
```

It should be added to the header using a property name 'authorization' and the username and password should be base64encoded as below

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);    
sample.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2009/01/using-basic-authentication-with-web-services.html

This has solved my problem. Hope it helps anybody else also.

Comment: Glad you got it solved :) I would be curious to see what that request xml ended up looking like.

Comment: @SfdcBat - I got lost in all the other drama on this question and completely overlooked how you were sending the credentials. Your answer is the typical way of doing it for http requests . Sometimes it is the most basic things. Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: @Eric yeah understand that . Its always about basics! :)

Answer (score 2):

To debug this issue you can create a temporary RequestBin URL by going to https://requestb.in/ - 
[image]
1. Click on "Create a RequestBin" and keep this window open 
2. Copy this URL and add to the remote site settings in SFDC
3. Replace original endpoint with this URL as per sample code below -

//Generated by wsdl2apex

```
public class docSampleComDocsample {
    public class EchoStringResponse_element {
        public String EchoStringResult;
        private String[] EchoStringResult_type_info = new String[]{'EchoStringResult','http://doc.sample.com/docSample',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://doc.sample.com/docSample','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'EchoStringResult'};
    }
    public class EchoString_element {
        public String input;
        private String[] input_type_info = new String[]{'input','http://doc.sample.com/docSample',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://doc.sample.com/docSample','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'input'};
    }
    public class DocSamplePort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://requestb.in/10vmy8b1';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://doc.sample.com/docSample', 'docSampleComDocsample'};
        public String EchoString(String input) {
            docSampleComDocsample.EchoString_element request_x = new docSampleComDocsample.EchoString_element();
            request_x.input = input;
            docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'urn:dotnet.callouttest.soap.sforce.com/EchoString',
              'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
              'EchoString',
              'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
              'EchoStringResponse',
              'docSampleComDocsample.EchoStringResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.EchoStringResult;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Perform callout, I executed this code from developer console-

   docSampleComDocsample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSampleComDocsample.DocSamplePort();
   String input = 'This is the input string';
   String output = stub.EchoString(input);
4. Go to RequestBin window and click on below icon to see the request payload - 
   [image]
5. The request payload will be shown as below - 
   [image]
6. Once the debug is complete you can remove the remote site settings and replace the endpoint in code with original endpiont

Comment: Thanks. What do we get by doing step 5 and 6 here?

Comment: Hi @SfdcBat, at step 5 just copy request RAW BODY payload and compare it with the working copy of request payload from SOAP UI to see if there is any difference in the request payload.

Comment: Can I use the payload details which you gave in step 5 and compare with my SOAP UI request to actual endpoint?

Comment: I didn't have complete WSDL therefore I used one of the sample it will not be useful for you.

Comment: I don't understand how using this can be helpuful to me. My wsdl and endpoint is from some other system which is expecting a different kind of request. I wont be able to replace that endpoint here.